# ArrayFormula and PRODUCT of all previous rows?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a column of percent changes (column A) and want to create a running total percent change (column B):

```
   A        B
-------  -------
100.00%  100.00%
 92.75%   92.75%
 97.23%   90.18%
100.00%   90.18%
100.56%   90.68%
```

This is easy with a formula in each cell of column B, starting with B1 and copying down:

```
=IF(B1="","",PRODUCT(B$1:B1))
```

However, I would like to change this to an ArrayFormula to avoid the need to continuously copy that formula down the column when rows are added.

Is this possible using ArrayFormula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back to school on this one. So you take logs, do a running sum, then antilog:

```
=ArrayFormula(10^mmult(if(column(indirect("A1:"&address(counta(A:A),counta(A:A))))>row(indirect("A1:"&address(counta(A:A),counta(A:A)))),0,1),log10(indirect("A1:A"&counta(A:A)))))
```

[image]

I forgot that you don't actually have to create a 2d array to do a running total, so can simplify to

```
=ArrayFormula(10^mmult(if(transpose(row((indirect("A1:A"&counta(A:A)))))>
row(indirect("A1:A"&counta(A:A))),0,1),log10(indirect("A1:A"&counta(A:A)))))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!  One modification I made is to use OFFSET instead of INDIRECT, which permits the formula updates when copied, and also seems a bit faster.  I changed `indirect("A1:A"&counta(A:A))` to `OFFSET(A1:A,0,0,COUNTA(A1:A))`

Comment: For anyone interested ... I ended up modifying the formula further to use COUNTIF instead of COUNTA as I found COUNTA produces false positives in some scenarios.  The final version replacing INDIRECT with OFFSET for my scenario looks like this:  `OFFSET(A1,0,0,COUNTIF(A1:A,">0"))`